# Elegant synonym for subject matter of a discipline

Tags: synonyms, writing, science, learning, philosophy

I am writing an essay on critical thinking. I am trying to find a word that allows me to separate the subject matter of a scientific discipline (i.e. chemistry, geology, etc.) from the underlying logic that comes with using or understanding the knowledge.

> Once a fundamental knowledge of physics is obtained, doing chemistry simply becomes a matter of applying critical skills to the _________

Comment: In what way are you making this split? It seems to me that ***discipline*** should cover it.

Comment: Do you really mean doing chemistry with a knowledge of physics, or is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the meaning of the word is supposed to be, that should go where you put *BLANK*.

Comment: Perhaps "applying critical skills to _the specifics_"

Comment: Sometimes "field" is used.  i.e.  The brilliant astro-physicist was known as the leader in his field.

Answer (score 2):

The only synonyms for that sense of *discipline* (meaning a "field of study"), which I could find were *subject area* and *speciality*.

I sense the term you need is ***subject area***.